# Question about solutions of nonlinear functional equation $f(x)^2=xf(2x)$

Tags: functional-equations

One of the basic nonlinear functional equations is the following one:
$$f(x)^2=xf(2x),\quad x>0\text.$$
I found out that functions $f(x)=2^{1-x}x\exp(cx)$ form the family of solutions of this equation. But do this family cover all possible solutions to this equation? Truly speaking, I have no idea how to answer to this question. Thank you.

Comment: Usually functional equations tend to have non continuous solutions as well, which might turn out weird.

Comment: Small detail: The $2^{-x} = e^{-\log(2) x}$ can be combined with the $e^{cx}$ (since $c$ is arbitrary) so your solution can simply be written $2xe^{cx}$.

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that non continuous solutions may exist but do they exist in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this family does not cover all solutions, nor even all *continuous* ones. The general solution is: take **any** function defined for $x\in[1,2)$ (which means an awful lot of possibilities, mind you!) and continue it both ways, up and down, using the expressions for $f(2x)$ via $f(x)$ and vice versa.

Comment: Oh, I see now! Its' just so simple. Thanks!